# Intel DPC++ 2024 compiled binary missing sycl7.dll and pi_win_proxy_loader.dll

Tags: c++, windows, icc

I'm using the `Intel(R) oneAPI DPC++ Compiler 2024` compiler to build my C++ code in Visual Studio:

[image]

[The version I downloaded](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/tool/oneapi-standalone-components.html#dpcpp-cpp) is:

[image]

When I run my app from within Visual Studio, it works. However, the debug or release version in the respective output directories miss DLLs from the Intel compiler directory (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\2024.0\bin`).

For debug:

- `sycl7d.dll`
- `pi_win_proxy_loaderd.dll`

For release:

- `sycl7.dll`
- `pi_win_proxy_loader.dll`

Even if I copy those DLLs into the debug and release directories respectively, the application does not run standalone:
`The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application`.

Is there anything else I'm missing or what should I do to make the application work outside of Visual Studio?

[This](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-oneAPI-Base-Toolkit/Executing-oneAPI-2024-0-0-built-exe-fails/td-p/1550013) is a related Intel forum post.

With [this](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Fortran-Compiler/dll-missing-from-compiled-Fortran-executable/m-p/1311174#M157324) suggestion (despite being for Fortran), it gave me the following output on CMD:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\debugger\2024.0\env>vars.bat
> was unexpected at this time.
```

Looks like the script isn't working as intended (yes, I also defined the environment variable `VS2022INSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview` because it wasn't automatically detected by the `Intel oneAPI command prompt`)

When building with the `MSVC` compiler, there are no such issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved by installing the Intel Compiler Runtime since that will provide the missing DLLs and so on. For more information, see [this](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-oneAPI-Base-Toolkit/Executing-oneAPI-2024-0-0-built-exe-fails/m-p/1560219#M3355) answer.